# Adding tabs (\t) in the appropriate spot to my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a code that requires tabs to put in it, but I cannot seem to figure out how to add the tabs appropriately. See below for my code and the doc string for what it should return, and what it returns instead. Maybe I should rethink my whole approach?

```
def display_game(guesses, clues):
'''(list, list) -> str
Given two lists of single character strings, return a string 
that  displays the current state of the game   
>>>display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'], ['b','b', 'b', 'b']])
'Guess\tClues\n****************\nY P G G\tb b\nO O G G\tb b b b\n'
'''
display = 'Guess\tClues\n****************\n'
for i in range(len(guesses)):
        for letter in guesses[i]:
            display += letter + ' '
        for letter in clues[i]:
            display += letter + ' '
        display += '\n'
return display
```

When I use it (using the doc string example), I get:

```
display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'],      ['b','b', 'b', 'b']])
```

'Guess\tClues\n****************\nY P G G b b \nO O G G b b b b \n'

Any attempt to put \t in the code has it turning out wrong (ex: with \t between each string instead of where they should be as per the doc string). Is anyone able to suggest how I may change things around? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just add it in between the for loops:

```
for i in range(len(guesses)):
        for letter in guesses[i]:
            display += letter + ' '
        display += '\t' # right here
        for letter in clues[i]:
            display += letter + ' '
        display += '\n'
return display
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question - adding + '\t\ beside letter (in display += letter) which I tried adds a tab between each character in the sublists in guess because its indented under the 'for letter in' loop but your method it adds the tab between sublists because the 'display += '\t' ' is not part of the 'for letter in' loop?

Comment: This leaves a trailing space after the last item in each guess before the tab is inserted, which will lead to badly formatted columns

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not add a tab in between the guess and the clue. You could simply add

`display += '\t'`

in between the first and second nested for loops, however, you then need to ensure that a trailing space is not added at the end of the first loop.

[`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join) is a better way to handle this as it only adds delimiter strings in between the items of a sequence:

```
>>> ' '.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a b c'
```

Notice that there is no trailing space character in the above. Applying that to your function:

```
def display_game(guesses, clues):
    display = 'Guess\tClues\n****************\n'
    for guess, clue in zip(guesses, clues):
        display += '{}\t{}\n'.format(' '.join(guess), ' '.join(clue))
    return display
```

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) is also used here to pair each guess and clue. Then it's simply a matter of using `str.join()` on the guess and clue, and building the string with the tab in the required place.

```
>>> assert(display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'], ['b','b', 'b', 'b']]) == 'Guess\tClues\n****************\nY P G G\tb b\nO O G G\tb b b b\n')
```

Comment: Using your code, although the `\t`'s are correctly placed, there are no tabs if you print the result.

Comment: @gommb: the tabs are there, is just that the second column starts on a tab stop, so the effect of the tab is not visible. You will see the same if you print the expected output string from the docstring of your function. The assert() statement above ensures that the function produces the required value.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Just add the tab between those two for loops of guesses and clues.

```
def display_game(guesses, clues):
    display = 'Guess \t Clues \n **************** \n'
    for i in range(len(guesses)):
        for letter in guesses[i]:
            display += letter + ' '
        display += '\t'
        for letter in clues[i]:
            display += letter + ' '
        display += '\n'
    return display

print(display_game('at', 'yk'))
```

This gave output:

```
Guess    Clues 
**************** 
a        y 
t        k
```